# After reboot sound goes through loudspeaker, not through wire headphones

Tags: sound, 22.04, headphones

There is Ubuntu 22.04 Jammy on the Dell laptop. When I attach wire headphones they work normally. However, the sound goes through loudspeaker after rebooting the computer. I think it is a small bug. I fix it reinserting the headphones. Is there a way to force the computer remembering that headphones are plugged?